# Why am I getting error while using "str.charAt(i) = str.charAt(i+1)" in a loop

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i=0; i<str.length();)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1))
            {
                for(int j=i;j<str.length();j++)
                    str.charAt(j)=str.charAt(j+1); //Here the error occurs
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
error: unexpected type
                str.charAt(j)=str.charAt(j+1);
                          ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

Comment: You can't assign to a function call. Also strings are immutable. Perhaps you could use a `StringBuilder` and the [`setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)) method. Hard to say without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: What do you expect this code to do exactly?  Its honestly a complete mess.

Comment: I think you are trying compare these two.
See difference between == & = operator

Answer (score 0):

`str.charAt(j)` returns a value. E.g. The character "a".

This would be the equivalent of writing this:

```
"a" = str.charAt(j+1); // Doesn't work
```

Instead you want to assign replace a character of the String `str`.

Here is one method of doing this is to convert the string to a char array.

```
char[] strCharArray= str.toCharArray();
strCharArray[j] = str.charAt(j+1)
```

Alternatively you could use a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.setCharAt(j, str.charAt(j+1));
```

Comment: Another issue is both of his `str.charAt(j+1)` and `str.charAt(i+1)` will always hit a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so this still won't run.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a getter to set a value.

use something like this :

```
str.setCharAt(j, str.charAt(j+1));
```

Comment: `String`s are immutable, there is no `setCharAt`.